# Button not reading in Selenium Python (chrome webdriver, protonmail)

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning to use selenium with python2 and am creating a program to login and compose a message using protonmail.

All is running smoothly until it gets to the line with the sidebar. I have verified that the xpath is accurate, and have experimented with get element by id, however continue to get the No Such Element exception. I have added a few lines to disable popups, so that isn't an issue.

Does anyone know what may be causing this? There has to be something I've overlooked.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

#disable notifications
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')

# open page
browser.get('http://mail.protonmail.com');
time.sleep(5)

#login
username = browser.find_element_by_id("username")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
username.send_keys("testproj")`enter code here`
password.send_keys("Testers_test123")
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_id("login_btn")
login_attempt.submit()
time.sleep(10)

#compose Message

sidebar = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pm_sidebar"]/button').click()
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML for the sidebar button you are trying to click. Have you tried adding a wait? `WebDriverWait` not `sleep()`

Comment: I am getting _Incorrect credentials_ Do you have a dummy credentials?

Comment: @DebanjanB- I got that message today as well. I think thelogin tests were executed too many times and locked me out. Changed credentials.

Answer (score 0):

try with single quotes inside the locator

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pm_sidebar']/button").click()
```

Also to help you more share your html code in text format. And you should use implicit or explicit waits instead of time.sleep its not best way for wait as it might take more or less time for element to appear. [check this out](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)